# OPC UA Java Build Failures

Tags: opc-ua

I git cloned from the github UA-Java repository https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java to a folder UA-Java.

In the root of UA-Java, I ran

```
mvn package
```

Then, again from the root of UA-Java

```
mvn install
```

Finally,

in the examples\basic

```
mvn package
```

I got build failures for each of those. The last-parts of outputs are at here [1](https://pastebin.com/Mh3x5hHD).

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tests are failing.

You can power through and ignore that by running `mvn clean install -DskipTests` at the root so it succeeds, then `mvn package` again in the examples to build your examples.

You might also consider opening an issue with the maintainers about the test failures if they're consistently failing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Yes. That worked. The versions of jars in the poms of the examples didn't match those of the main stack, which has been incremented. So I changed the poms accordingly. The example servers and clients seem to have bugs, although some work.

Comment: Yes. I'd visited the Eclipse site of Milo few days ago, but since it is in incubation, no downloads are available. I guess I missed the github. I'll try the snapshot. Thanks. Good to see you there.

Comment: Ooph, I didn't realize anybody ever landed on the Eclipse project pages. Maybe it's time I get the project a logo and work on that page a bit :/